# Angular 2.0.0-rc.1: How to test elements on the view or content (e.g. @ViewChildren, @ContentChildren)

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I have a component that gets data from a service which creates children on the `View`. Those children are only available when the `View` is created. In my example below the `View` is not created before it reaches its tests, thus test 2 fails.

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-to-test',
  providers: [Service],
  directives: [NgFor, ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <child [data]="childData" *ngFor="let childData of data"></child>
})

export class ComponentToTest implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  private data: any;

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  private getData() {
    // async fetch data from a service
  }
}
```

spec:

```
describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  beforeEach(inject([ComponentToTest], (component: ComponentToTest) => {
    component.ngOnInit();
  }));


  it('should initialise data', inject([ComponentToTest], (component: ComponentToTest, service: Service) => {
    return service.getData().toPromise().then(() => {
      expect(component.data).toBeDefined();
    })
  }));

  it('should initialise children', inject([ComponentToTest], (component: ComponentToTest, service: Service) => {
    return service.getData().toPromise().then(() => {
      expect(component.children).toBeDefined();
    })
  }));
});
```

Test 1 passes, test 2 fails. How do you test something that is created after the `View` or `Content` is initialised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting a component only creates an instance of the component class but no lifecycle callbacks will be called and no view created.

You need to use the `TestComponentBuilder` instead:

```
describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  let component: ComponentToTest;
  beforeEach(async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    tcb.createAsync(ComponentToTest).then((fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentToTest>) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      // component.ngOnInit(); // called by `fixture.detectChanges()`
    });
  })));

  it('should initialise children', () => {
    expect(component.children).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

To ensure that the test doesn't end before all async execution is done also use `async()` like already mentioned by Thierry.

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the `async` function:

```
it('should initialise children', async(inject([ComponentToTest], (component: ComponentToTest, service: Service) => {
  return service.getData().toPromise().then(() => {
    expect(component.children).toBeDefined();
  });
})));
```

From the documentation:

> Wraps a test function in an asynchronous test zone. The test will automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone are done. Can be used to wrap an inject call